# jquery change different text in divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hallo,

I have three different divs and a paragraph in each one of them.

I would like to click on div 1 and text 1 changes - if I click on div 2, text 2 changes while text 1 is changing back to normal...

Just the text in the div where I just clicked should change. Since I am a newbie to jquery I can just achieve that all the texts are changing, but not the single one.

Who can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: you also need to provide some html markup and code that you have tried

Comment: 21 Questions and just 1 accepted answer, ...@Densie surely you scare SO answerers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the trick - first populate data for each div with the original content, then bind click event that sets everything back to original data, and sets itself to new text:

http://jsfiddle.net/billymoon/zAhJv/

```
$('div').each(function(){
    $(this).data({original:$(this).text()})  
})
$('div').click(function(){
    $('div').each(function(){
        $(this).text($(this).data('original'))
    })
    $(this).text('new text')
})
```